# After update classpath 3.0.0 GreenDao not working

Tags: android, build.gradle, greendao

Yesterday I update my Android Studio. After updating if I run GreenDao application I am getting error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/greenrobot/greendao/generator/Schema
    at com.example.ApplicationDaoGenerator.main(ApplicationDaoGenerator.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.greenrobot.greendao.generator.Schema
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843031/noclassdeffounderror-when-trying-to-run-daogenerator-for-greendao) solution. But no luck. And also I tried with [this](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/issues/619) link. This is also not help to me. Please let me any idea to resolve this issue.

I am using `compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-generator:3.2.2'`.

My application generator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.bla.bla.dao"); 
        schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault();    
        createTables(schema);

        try {
            new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema,"./app/src/main/java");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried the following too. But no luck

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.example.ApplicationDaoGenerator"


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao-generator:3.2.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

Comment: exactly the same error! I have tried everything but still no luck

Comment: @MartaTenés.. Actually you can try the [this](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/generator/#Triggering_generation). Execute the Gradle run task. So that all the tables will generated. But if we run the java class we will face the same issue. But if we run the Gradle run task Table will generate. Try that.

Comment: yeah thank you! I 've noticed of this just minutes ago! OMG what a headache :S

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes. Solved.. But not able to run java class. If I run the Java class I am getting same error..

Comment: yeah same issue. At least we can generate our classes ;)

Comment: Yes.!! Happy Coding..!!